# flags, compilers and algorithm strategies to optimise Fortran loops

Tags: optimization, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, compiler-flags

I'm studying around the impact of unrolling and optimisation flags on Fortran code. I come up with the following, very trivial, case:

```
program do_order
implicit none

integer :: j, s, n, nLoops
integer, dimension(4) :: Iv
real*8, dimension(16, 4) :: tmp, Ov
real :: start, finish

nLoops = 1000000

!! Initialize the values of Input vector;
do n = 1,4
    Iv(n) = n**2
end do

!! Explicit Do-loop + implicit Do-loop working across columns (to be Fortran efficient)
call cpu_time(start)
    do n = 1, nLoops
        tmp = 0.d0
        Ov = 0.d0
        do j = 1,4
            tmp(1:Iv(j),j) = Ov(1:Iv(j),j) - 10.0d0
        end do
    end do
call cpu_time(finish)

print '("Loop-1 Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

tmp = 0.d0
Ov = 0.d0

!! Un-rolled loop + implicit Do-loop 
call cpu_time(start)
    do n = 1, nLoops
        tmp = 0.d0
        Ov = 0.d0
           tmp(1:Iv(1),1) = Ov(1:Iv(1),1) - 10.0d0
           tmp(1:Iv(2),2) = Ov(1:Iv(2),2) - 10.0d0
           tmp(1:Iv(3),3) = Ov(1:Iv(3),3) - 10.0d0
           tmp(1:Iv(4),4) = Ov(1:Iv(4),4) - 10.0d0
    end do
call cpu_time(finish)

print '("Loop-2 Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

end program
```

Compiled with: `-O3 -mprefer-avx128` flags, gives me the following timing:

> Loop-1 Time =  4.487 seconds.
> Loop-2 Time =  3.657 seconds.

I've used Gfort: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0. I have access also to
Ifort 19.1.3.304. The same test with Ifort `-O3` gives me:

> Loop-1 Time =  0.939 seconds.
> Loop-2 Time =  0.873 seconds.

**My questions:**

- Why the huge gap in performance between Gfort and Ifort?
- did I unrolled the second loop correctly?
- Are there other optimization flags to speedup the code even more (i.e. [Loop unrolling & optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084648/1753931), [Decreasing the fortran run time by extra optimization flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641693/1753931))?
- Are there other strategies to speedup the code even more (without moving to multithreading, for now)?

Comment: Be aware of what does the `cpu_time()` subroutine actually measure. CPU time is different from the clock time the computation actually takes but it may be useful to shield from the effect of other processes running on the same computer.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks for your feedback. I've used the `system_clock` command, yet the second loop is still faster:
```Loop-1: CPU Time =  5.632 seconds.
Loop-1: System Clock =  5.632 seconds.
Loop-2: CPU Time =  5.395 seconds.
Loop-2: System Clock =  5.396 seconds.```

And for the IFort runs:

```Loop-1: CPU Time =  0.925 seconds.
Loop-1: System Clock =  0.928 seconds.
Loop-2: CPU Time =  0.867 seconds.
Loop-2: System Clock =  0.870 seconds.
```

Comment: The intel !DEC$ and !DIR$ can be used.
That 3.6 versus 0.9 seconds looks like a vector SIMD factor of 4.
I usually (always) prefer SIMD to multithreaded in these examples. Your second “loop” may be better as a loop if it help gfortran to optimise it. However I almost always use fort, so it is a guess.